# Indexing logs with es-hadoop

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hdfs, avro

I am new to elasticsearch and want to index my website logs which are stored on HDFS for fast querying.
I have a well structured pipeline which runs a script every 20 minutes to ingest the data into HDFS.
I want to integrate elasticsearch with it, so that it also indexes these logs based on particular field(s) and thereby giving faster query results using spark SQL.
So, my question is, can I index my data based on particular field(s) only?
Also, my logs are saved in avro file format. Does es provides a way to directly index avro serialized data or do I need to convert it into some other format?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to look at Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana stack that should be good enough to full fill your requirement. Putting it on HDFS and then using ES would be additional overhead.

Instead, you can use Logstash to pump data into ES, index on whatever fields you wish to query and build easy dashboards in less than 10 minutes of exercise. Take a look at this tutorial for better step-by-step guide.

http://hadooptutorials.co.in/tutorials/elasticsearch/log-analytics-using-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana.html

Comment: So, If I store the logs in elasticsearch as well, won't it require double the space?

Comment: Well I meant, ONLY storing into ES.